# How to receive error emails using ElmahCore

Tags: c#, .net-core, sendgrid, elmah

I receive error log using elmahcore but I want to receive the errors by email. How do I do that?

This is how I receive the errors in database.

```
  services.AddElmah<SqlErrorLog>(options =>
        {
            options.ConnectionString = Configuration["ElmahConnection"];
            options.ApplicationName = Configuration["ApplicationName"];               
        });
```

I am using sendgrid email but I don't know how to implement it to ElmahCOre.

```
EmailOptions emailOptions = new EmailOptions
        {
            MailRecipient = "email@some.com"
        };
     services.AddElmah<XmlFileErrorLog>(options =>
        {
            options.Path = @"errors";
            options.LogPath = "~/logs";
            options.Notifiers.Add(new ErrorMailNotifier("Email", emailOptions));
        });
```

emailClass

```
  SendGridClient client = new SendGridClient(".....");
  SendGridMessage mail = new SendGridMessage();      
  mail.AddTo(new EmailAddress(email));
  mail.From ="email";           
  client.SendEmailAsync(mail);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to receive emails from ElmahCore using sendgrid and also get in SQL.

```
   EmailOptions emailOptions = new EmailOptions
        {
            MailRecipient = "email@email.com",
            MailSender = "email@email.com",
            SmtpServer = "smtp.sendgrid.net",
            AuthUserName = "loginUsername",
            AuthPassword = "loginPassword"
        };
        services.AddElmah<SqlErrorLog>(options =>
        {
            options.ConnectionString = Configuration["ElmahConnection"];
            options.ApplicationName = Configuration["ApplicationName"];
            options.Notifiers.Add(new ErrorMailNotifier("Email", emailOptions));
        });
```